# Сохранение состояния скрола при пересоздании PagedList

Tags: android, android-fragment, recyclerview, view, pagination

При пересоздании View Fragmenta пересоздается мой RecyclerView, в который я добавляю PagedList

```
 binding.moviesRecycler.adapter = recyclerViewCommand.newRecyclerViewAdapter().also {  adapter ->
            viewModel.newLists?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){
                adapter.submitList(it)
            }
        }
```

При пересоздании View позиция скролла сбрасывается в состояние 0, я пробовал сохранять состояние

```
 adapterMovie!!.stateRestorationPolicy = RecyclerView.Adapter.StateRestorationPolicy.PREVENT_WHEN_EMPTY
```

И это работает, но при пересоздании, данный из базы данных (Room) начинают грузится заново, и в итоге он загружает изначально 40 записей, если к моменту пересоздания скролл стоял на одном из этих 40 элементов при пересоздании состояние скролла сохранится, но есть >40 состояние скролла будет 0, как это поправить?

Comment: можно попробовать установить setItemViewCacheSize  что бы фрагменты внутри recycler кешировались и не пересоздавались. Или искать что то здесь https://stackoverflow.com/q/27816217/7540461

Comment: Я не переворачиваю экран, что бы вызывать методы сохранения состояния через bundle, я открываю другой фрагмент, методом replace и потом нажимаю назад